# python Selenium, не могу кликнуть по ютубу

Tags: python

Не могу нажать кнопку на ютубе при загрузке видео, хотя раньше все работало все хорошо.

А именно:

Не нажимается кнопка "Нет, это видео не для детей" как бы я не пробовал, разными методами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущий код такой:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tp-yt-paper-radio-button[@name='VIDEO_MADE_FOR_KIDS_NOT_MFK']//div[@id='offRadio']")
```

А так же по кнопке "Далее"
В чем может быть дело? Загрузка видео происходит успешно, название ролика тоже устанавливаю.

Comment: Ошибку какую выдает?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Вообще никакую, просто не кликает

Comment: Ну конечно, ведь нужно вызвать метод click, чтобы кликнуть

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Я вызываю просто не весь код скинул)) не в этом дело 100%

Comment: Ну значит надо весь код скинуть, потому что если на этой строчке нет ошибок, значит элемент найден, можете эту строчку присвоить переменной и посмотреть что она в себе содержит

Comment: @ClarkDevlin '<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0d2299b93159e5ab699b5a0f9e9aeee5", element="6fb652ae-b482-4fe0-9bd0-3d8ee54b4e86")>' Вот что выдала переменная

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130608/discussion-between-clark-devlin-and-).